# Subscription Refetch Updating Data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, subscription, prisma

I wanted to get your opinion on something.

I'm trying to understand how a subscription works. however, I couldn't find a way to pull an array of objects in a subscription. for example, if I use createMany, I can not return all the result via subscription.

The second issue is if I return a single item for example if it's a new item, I have to "manually (air quote)" add that item to the list that is already displayed. But this feels to me I don't actually display real-time true data.

So my question is using something like

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    // refetching original query when subscription is triggered
    refetch();
 }, [updatedNotificationData]);
```

would there be any downside like hitting up the server more than I should? let's say every time there is a refetching happens I might be pulling thousands of notifications (I know there is caching but still) or is there a better way to deal with bringing new data.

Also, I tried adding subscribed data to the original list but for some reason react adds 2 of the same item every time.

Thanks in advance if you can give me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I use createMany, I can not return all the result via subscription.

That shouldn't be a problem if you define the return type of the subscription as array.

```
type Subscription{
  onChange:[ObjectType]
}
```

It would allow you to avoid fetching again but updating cache can get a bit complicated.

> Also, I tried adding subscribed data to the original list but for some reason react adds 2 of the same item every time.

In case you are using the the subscribeToMore method it's not really reacts fault but the way how the updateQuery method works: [github issue regarding this](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3480).

My workaround was to subscribe via the useSubscription hook and handle the cache modifications inside the onSubscriptionData callback [apollo documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/#options) and also setting the useQuery hooks skip option once I get the data so it wont query on each rerender.